# How to define config.logging for fluentd in nomad jobspec

Tags: logging, fluentd, nomad

I have a waypoint.hcl that completes a nomad jobspec.
I need to use fluentd to handle logging.

Here is a stripped, minimal example of a jobspec file. What values should I give env, tag, and labels?

```
job "${jobname}" {
  type = "system"
  group "${task}" {
    task "${task}" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {
        image   = "${image}"
        command = "/path/entrypoint.sh"
        logging {
          type = "fluentd"
          config {
            labels = "application,environment"
            fluentd-address = "localhost:24224"
            env = "HOSTNAME"
            # tag = "docker.${image}/${jobname}/${task}"
            tag = "docker.{{.ImageName}}/{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}"
            fluentd-async = "true"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```